# Outlook SentMailFolder macro

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am attempting to create a macro to run a rule on my sent item folder. But keep running into "Object variable or With block variable not set" asterisks
I'm a newbie at this so any help is appreciated.

Here is another failed attempt

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   runRulesOnSentMailFolder
End Sub

Sub runRulesOnSentMailFolder()
    Dim st As Outlook.Store
    Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
    Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim ruleList As String
    Dim rulePrefix As String
    Dim ruleFolder As Long

```
'
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As NameSpace


ruleFolder = olFolderSentMail
rulePrefix = "SENT_Mail_"

Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objSentmailfolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(ruleFolder)

' get default store (where rules live)
Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
' get rules
Set myRules = st.GetRules
```

' iterate all the rules
    For Each rl In myRules
        ' determine if it's an Inbox rule and rule name prefix matches
        If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive And Left(rl.Name, Len(rulePrefix)) = rulePrefix Then

```
        ' if so, run it
        rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True, Folder:=objSentmailfolder
        count = count + 1
        ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.Name
    End If
****Next****

' tell the user what you did
ruleList = "These rules were executed against the folder: " & objSentmailfolder.Name & vbCrLf & ruleList
MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: runRulesOnSentMailFolder"

Set rl = Nothing
Set st = Nothing
Set myRules = Nothing
Set objSentmailfolder = Nothing
Set objNS = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Something seems to be missing in the code - or do you expect it to magically loop `rl` over myRules? The comment _’ iterate all the rules_ will not make it loop.

Comment: Alright in this we are agreed. Something is missing. I am a complete newbie cutting and pasting trying to stumble through this, any specific directions are appreciated. Here is another attempt that fails.